# The column names of my CSV files are years in yyyy format. How do I refer to these columns using "." operator in d.columnName?

Tags: csv, d3.js

The columns of my CSV file are : "1960","1961","1962","1963","1964","1965","1966","1967"

```
 var Max = d3.max(data, function(d) { 
   return d.1967; 
   }
```

the above code doesn't work. Error shown in browser console :

> SyntaxError: missing ; before statement

So how do I refer to these columns ?

Comment: `return d[1967];` or `return d['1967'];`

Comment: That works, thanks. write it as an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After CSV file is read objects will be created with properties like:

```
{
    1960: 55,
    1961: 12,
    ...
    1967: 77
}
```

Object property names can be specified as strings or numbers but numeric property names are converted to strings. To retrieve those properties you cannot use notation 
`d.'1961'` or `d.1961`. You have to use `d['1961']`.